# Magento2 : Logged-in user has to re-login before checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, login

- Login in
- Add product to cart
- In top bar there is text "Welcome Michael Surname", but there is
  still option to sign-in and sign-up next to it.
- Go to cart > checkout
- Login prompt is displayed
  [image]

minicart code

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart desktop" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
       <svg class="cart-icon"><use xlink:href="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icon-sprite.svg#cart');?>"></use></svg>
            <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="action showcart mobile" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
       <svg class="cart-icon"><use xlink:href="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icon-sprite.svg#cart');?>"></use></svg>
            <span class="counter qty empty">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart.desktop",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <div data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: because you disable guest checkout from adminpanel or you customize checkout module ??

Comment: Yes i have disable guest checkout but it showing when i'm already logged ig by login page

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: version is 2.2.2

Comment: it look like customer is semi logged in,customer name is not displaying http://prntscr.com/jdz9sy

Comment: Do you have any custom module related with the checkout?

Comment: No i havent add any module, I use default checkout

Comment: Are you using any custom theme?

Comment: Can you share your minicart code that you customize?

Comment: I have update my ans.

Answer (score 3):

i have faced similar issue earlier and have got resolved the issue, hope it helps.It's better to extend it in custom module but for quick check you test it in core and later can extend it in your module.Goto to your SesionManager.php in path

```
vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
```

Search for the function regenerateId() and replace the below code

```
public function regenerateId()
    {
        if (headers_sent()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
            $oldSessionId = session_id();            
            session_regenerate_id();   //regen the session
            $new_session_id = session_id();

            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;

            // Set destroy timestamp
            $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();

            // Write and close current session;
            session_commit();
            $oldSession = $_SESSION;   //called after destroy - see destroy!
            // Start session with new session ID
            session_id($new_session_id);
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
            session_start();
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
            // New session does not need them
            unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
            unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);  
        } else {
            session_start();
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);

        if ($this->sessionConfig->getUseCookies()) {
            $this->clearSubDomainSessionCookie();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

then search for start() and replace it with

```
 public function start()
    {
        if (!$this->isSessionExists()) {
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('session_start');

            try {
                $this->appState->getAreaCode();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException(
                    new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                        'Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.'
                    ),
                    $e
                );
            }

            // Need to apply the config options so they can be ready by session_start
            $this->initIniOptions();
            $this->registerSaveHandler();
            if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
             // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
             session_commit();
             session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
             }
            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])) {
               if ($_SESSION['destroyed'] < time()-300) {
                   $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);

               }
            }
            $this->validator->validate($this);

            register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);

            $this->_addHost();
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('session_start');
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);
        return $this;
    }
```

Note:It worked for me and i got this solution from github [#Tickect:12362](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362) you can check for reference from the link.